# Finding the minimum of Condition number for this matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $A=\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{0.1\alpha }&{0.1\alpha }\\
1&{1.5}
\end{array}} \right]$. How can we find minimum of condition number $k(A)=\Vert A\Vert \Vert A^{-1} \Vert$ (Assume $\infty$-Norm)? And for what value of $\alpha$?

Comment: Is it the  Frobenius norm?

Comment: You can assume Inf Norm.

Comment: Could you edit your question so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $A$ is singular if and only if $\alpha = 0$. Suppose $\alpha \neq 0$ and assume the infinity norm. Thus,

$$\|A\|_{\infty} =\begin{cases} -0.2\alpha, & \mbox{if } \alpha \leq -12.5 \\ 2.5, & \mbox{if } -12.5 < \alpha < 12.5\\ 0.2\alpha, & \mbox{if } \alpha \geq 12.5  \end{cases}.$$

We have
\begin{equation}
A^{-1} =  \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
30/\alpha & -2  \\
-20/\alpha& 2\\
\end{array} \right]
\end{equation} and $$\|A^{-1}\|_{\infty} =\begin{cases} -\frac{30}{\alpha} + 2, & \mbox{if } \alpha < 0 \\ \frac{30}{\alpha} +2, & \mbox{if } \alpha > 0  \end{cases}.$$ Hence,

$$k(A) =\begin{cases} -0.4\alpha +6, & \mbox{if } \alpha \leq -12.5 \\ 5-\frac{75}{\alpha}, & \mbox{if } -12.5 < \alpha < 0\\  5+\frac{75}{\alpha}, & \mbox{if } 0 < \alpha < 12.5\\0.4\alpha + 6, & \mbox{if } \alpha \geq 12.5  \end{cases}.$$

The minimal value of $k(A)$ is $11$ for $\alpha = \pm 12.5.$